# For-Each Loop Incompatible Types

Tags: java, database-design, foreach, incompatibletypeerror

I'm working on a project that creates a virtual database for films. I have two classes: MovieEntry (for the individual movie entry) and MovieDatabase (the larger class that contains the database and allows for additions, etc.) I'm getting a few errors, the first of them being that in the searchTitle method it says that Database is of an incompatible type. Can anyone tell me how to do these for-each loops? I read the book and I thought the ArrayList was supposed to go there but apparently not.

```
**import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class MovieDatabase
{
   private ArrayList<MovieEntry> Database = new ArrayList<MovieEntry>();
   public MovieDatabase(){
       ArrayList<MovieDatabase> Database = new ArrayList<MovieDatabase>(0);
    }

   public int countTitles() throws IOException{
   Scanner fileScan;
   fileScan = new Scanner (new File("movies.txt"));
   int count = 0;
   String movieCount;
   while(fileScan.hasNext()){
       movieCount = fileScan.nextLine();
       count++;
    }
   return count;
}

   public void addMovie(MovieEntry m){
       Database.add(m);
    }

   public ArrayList<MovieEntry> searchTitle(String substring){
       for (String title : Database)
          System.out.println(title);
          return null;
    }

   public ArrayList<MovieEntry> searchGenre(String substring){
       for (String genre : Database)
          System.out.println(genre);
          return null;
    }

   public ArrayList<MovieEntry> searchDirector (String str){
       for (String director : Database)
          System.out.println(director);
          return null;
    }

   public ArrayList<MovieEntry> searchYear (int yr){
       ArrayList <String> yearMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
       for (String s : Database)
       s.getYear();
        if(yearMatches.contains(y) == false){
           yearMatches.add(y);
        }
       return yearMatches;
    }

   public ArrayList<MovieEntry> searchYear(int from, int to){
       ArrayList <String> Matches = new ArrayList<String>();
       for(Student s : movies);
          Matches.add();
       return Matches;
    }

   public void readMovieData(String movies){
       String info;
       try{
           Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(new File(movies));
           Scanner lineReader;

           while(fileReader.hasNext()){
               info = fileReader.nextLine();

               lineReader = new Scanner(info);
               lineReader.useDelimiter(":");

               String title = lineReader.next();
               String director = lineReader.next();
               String genre = lineReader.next();
               int year = lineReader.nextInt();
            }

        }catch(FileNotFoundException error){
            System.out.println("File not found.");

        }catch(IOException error){
            System.out.println("Oops! Something went wrong.");
        }
    }



 public int countGenres(){
    String g;
    ArrayList <String> gList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(Student s : movies){
      String g = s.getGenre();
      if(gList.contains(g) == false){
        gList.add(g);
      }
      return gList.size();
    }
    }
    public int countDirectors(){
     ArrayList <String> dList = new ArrayList<String>();
     for(Student s : movies){
        String d = s.getDirector();
        if(dList.contains(d) == false){
            dList.add(d);
        }
        return dList.size();
     }

     }

    public String listGenres(){
        ArrayList <String> genreList = new ArrayList<String>();

    }

}**
```

Comment: Can you add declaration of `movies`.

Answer (score 2):

The type of the foreach variable (`String`, in the case of the loop in your `searchTitle` method) must be compatible with the type parameter (`MovieEntry`) of the parameterized type (`ArrayList<MovieEntry>`). This is clearly not the case. The following foreach loop would work:

```
for (MovieEntry title : Database) {
    System.out.println(title);
}
```

Please consider following the convention of using lowercase names for fields, i.e. call your `ArrayList<MovieEntry>` with a name such as `database` instead of `Database`.

Answer (score 1):

Well

```
for (Type obj : Collection) {...}
```

works only if the collection holds elements of type Type. This practically in your case means:

```
for (MovieDatabase database : Database) {...}
```

will work because Database is ArrayList holding the type MovieDatabase:

```
ArrayList<MovieDatabase> Database= new ArrayList<MovieDatabase>();
```

if you want to loop over titles in database you have to provide a method that gives back the list of Strings of titles, for example

```
public ArrayList<String> getTitles() {...}
....
for (String title : Database.getTitles()) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Database property (should be database, lowercase), is of type:

```
ArrayList<MovieDatabase>
```

And you're trying to iterate over it using a String as the element type.

Your foreach should be:

```
for(MovieDatabase element: Database){
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your `for-each` loop should look something like this (this is just an example so you'll have to adapt it for yours)

```
ArrayList<MovieEntry> list = new ArrayList<MovieEntry>();
...
for(MovieEntry m : list) {
   ...
}
```

an `ArrayList` is a valid thing to loop over but in your case you are trying to get `Strings` when your list doesn't hold `Strings` then you are calling methods on those `Strings` that `String` doesn't support. You have to use the right type for each list.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
private ArrayList<MovieEntry> Database = new ArrayList<MovieEntry>();
public MovieDatabase(){
   ArrayList<MovieDatabase> Database = new ArrayList<MovieDatabase>(0);
}
```

to

```
private ArrayList<MovieEntry> Database;;
public MovieDatabase(){
   Database = new ArrayList<MovieDatabase>(0);
}
```